# Macro: Delete row if value does not match this or that

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to modify the following code that if it does not match "X" or "Y" then delete the entire row. I tried to add just '"Or "Y"' but I get a type mismatch

```
For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow + 1 Step -1
     With .Cells(Lrow, "AY")
        If Not IsError(.Value) Then
            If Not .Value Like "X" Then .EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
Next Lrow
```

Any thoughts? Or suggestions for replacement?

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete the row if AY=X or Y? It's not clear.

Comment: I want to delete the row if the value in AY does not equal X or Y.

Comment: Would you care to edit your question then, as it says the complete opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very careful using `AND`s and `OR`s around `Not` - you have to think it through:

NOTE. `NOT(a`***`OR`***`b)` is the same as `NOT(a)`***`AND`***`NOT(b)`

The following code will do what you need:

```
For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow + 1 Step -1
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(Lrow, "AY")
        If Not (.Text = "X" Or .Text = "Y") Then .EntireRow.Delete
    End With
Next Lrow
```

The following line would also work instead:

```
       If Not (.Text = "X") And Not(.Text = "Y") Then .EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the code below::

```
For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow + 1 Step -1
     With .Cells(Lrow, "AY")
        If Not IsError(.Value) Then
            If .Value <> "X" AND .Value <> "Y" Then .EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
Next Lrow
```

Comment: I tried it. Its past the mismatch error but it is still deleting value Y

Comment: I've updated my answer as I've just noticed you want to keep the rows that contain either X or Y...

Comment: The question has been confusingly worded, but I don't think this will do as the OP wants. E.g if the cell equals X then `.Value <> "Y"` will be true and the row will be deleted.

Comment: @SJR thanks for the insight, I've updated my answer to AND instead or OR,.. I think this should resolve the issue.